# CSS positioning with Angular Material? Left (start), center, right (end), columns?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I know Bootstrap and AngularJS Material. I'm learning Angular Material but I can't find CSS positioning such as left (start), center, right (end) or column layouts. For example, let's put "Instructions" on the left and a "close" icon on the right, on a single line.

[image]

In AngularJS Material I use `layout-align`:

```html
<div layout="row">
      <span layout-align="start">
        <p class="md-title">Instructions</p>
      </span>
      <span flex></span>
      <span layout-align="end">
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="toggleInstructions()">
          <md-icon md-svg-src="media/icons/ic_close_24px.svg" aria-label="Close dialog"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </span>
    </div>
```

With Angular Material I can't find anything for CSS positioning. I tried using plain CSS but the two elements are now on two lines:

[image]

Here's the Angular HTML with plain CSS:

```html
<mat-card class="instructions" *ngIf="showInstructions">
    <mat-card-title>
       <span style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-start;">Instructions</span>
       <i class="material-icons" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">close</i>
    </mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

I see nothing in the [Angular Material guide](https://material.angular.io/) about CSS positioning. Does Angular Material no longer help with CSS positioning?

Comment: Take a look at [Angular Flex Layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout), which is a declarative approach for CSS flexbox and grids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I run into similar problems or situations. A little bit of layouting can be performed with the Grid list but in my opinion a bit very general.
Most times I use the flex layout of CSS. Sometimes it's a bit tricky, but for me it works.

In your case, you have to make the "mat-card-title" also as "display: flex" and use "flex-direction: row". Maybe need to set the flex attribute of your "span" and "i" to needed ratio...

This is a good flex tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks, the CSS-Tricks guide is excellent!  I now see that CSS positioning has improved to the point where Bootstrap and Material are no longer needed for positioning. I did coding bootcamp in 2015 and we had a full week on CSS positioning and we never become adept at it. Flex had just been spec'd but wasn't supported by browsers. It was a relief to learn Bootstrap. I'm happy to see that CSS is so good now.